# How to Show two Admob Native ads on same activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to use 2 Admob native ads in the same activity but with different sizes...
I already have successfully implemented one ad. now I want to show one more native ad in the same activity. How to do it properly

Admob implementation in the activity

```
private void populateUnifiedNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd, UnifiedNativeAdView
            adView) {
        // Set the media view. Media content will be automatically populated in the media view once
        MediaView mediaView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media);
        adView.setMediaView(mediaView);

        // Set other ad assets.
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_app_icon));
        adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price));
        adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_stars));
        adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store));
        adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser));

        // The headline is guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());

        // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
        // check before trying to display them.
        if (nativeAd.getBody() == null) {
            adView.getBodyView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getBodyView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getCallToAction() == null) {
            adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getIcon() == null) {
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(
                    nativeAd.getIcon().getDrawable());
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (nativeAd.getPrice() == null) {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAd.getPrice());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                    .setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // This method tells the Google Mobile Ads SDK that you have finished populating your
        // native ad view with this native ad. The SDK will populate the adView's MediaView
        // with the media content from this native ad.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

        // Get the video controller for the ad. One will always be provided, even if the ad doesn't
        // have a video asset.
        VideoController vc = nativeAd.getVideoController();

        // Updates the UI to say whether or not this ad has a video asset.
        if (vc.hasVideoContent()) {

            // Create a new VideoLifecycleCallbacks object and pass it to the VideoController. The
            // VideoController will call methods on this object when events occur in the video
            // lifecycle.
            vc.setVideoLifecycleCallbacks(new VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoEnd() {
                    // Publishers should allow native ads to complete video playback before
                    // refreshing or replacing them with another ad in the same UI location.

                    super.onVideoEnd();
                }
            });
        } else {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a request for a new native ad based on the boolean parameters and calls the
     * corresponding "populate" method when one is successfully returned.
     */
    private void refreshAd() {

        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.admob_native_advance));

        builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                // You must call destroy on old ads when you are done with them,
                // otherwise you will have a memory leak.
                if (nativeAd != null) {
                    nativeAd.destroy();
                }
//                nativeAd = unifiedNativeAd;
//
//
//                RelativeLayout relativeLayout =
//                        findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder);
//                UnifiedNativeAdView adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
//                        .inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null);
//                populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
//
//
//                relativeLayout.removeAllViews();
//                relativeLayout.addView(adView);

                NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                        NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
                TemplateView adView = findViewById(R.id.adview);
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adView.setStyles(styles);
                adView.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);
            }

        });

        VideoOptions videoOptions = new VideoOptions.Builder()
                .build();

        NativeAdOptions adOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                .setVideoOptions(videoOptions)
                .build();

        builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions);

        AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Log.w(HELPER_TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: " + errorCode);
            }
        }).build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build());
    }
```

1st AdMob native ad layout (implemented successfully)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView
        android:id="@+id/native_ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/dark_bg"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/primary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/icon"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_text_size_large"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/second_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/primary"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/gnt_ad_indicator_height"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:numStars="0"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_text_size_small" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/secondary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gnt_no_margin"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_text_size_small" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cta"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/main_ad_button"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textColor="@color/gnt_white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ad_text_background"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_notification_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="Ad"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/gnt_ad_indicator_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
</merge>
```

2nd AdMob layout file (needs to be implemented)

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/dark_bg"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView style="@style/AppTheme.AdAttribution"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_app_icon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_headline"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#0000FF"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ad_advertiser"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="bottom"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/ad_stars"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:isIndicator="true"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:stepSize="0.5" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_body"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_media"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="105dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_price"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_store"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:background="@drawable/main_ad_button"
                        android:id="@+id/ad_call_to_action"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
```

Comment: generalize the initialization and loading unified ad. while initialization , you should consider passing the framelayout which is the container of the ad and AD layout. that would help you to call native ad as many time as you want.

Comment: can you show a code example

Comment: Can you still use UnifiedNativeAd?
It looks replaced by NativeAd in Mobile Ads SDK (Android) v20 as this link 
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration

Answer (score 1):

Create a Class by Name **AdUtils** which has initialize and load the ad

```
public class AdUtils {

private Context context;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;
private int nativeAdLayout;
private String nativeAdsId;

private UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd;
private NativeAdListener nativeAdListener;

public void setNativeAdListener(NativeAdListener nativeAdListener){
    this.nativeAdListener= nativeAdListener;
}

 public AdUtils(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public void loadNativeAd(FrameLayout frameLayout, int nativeAdLayout, String nativeAdsId) {
    this.nativeAdLayout = nativeAdLayout;
    this.frameLayout = frameLayout;
    this.nativeAdsId = nativeAdsId;
    this.nativeAd = loadNativeAd();
}

private UnifiedNativeAd loadNativeAd() {
    if ((nativeAdLayout == -1 && frameLayout == null)) {
        return null;
    }

    final UnifiedNativeAd[] nativeAd = {null};
    AdLoader.Builder builder;
    builder = new AdLoader.Builder(context, nativeAdsId);
    builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd -> {

        if (nativeAd[0] != null) {
            nativeAd[0].destroy();
        }
        nativeAd[0] = unifiedNativeAd;
        UnifiedNativeAdView adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(nativeAdLayout, null);
        populateNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        frameLayout.addView(adView);

        if (nativeAdListener != null) {
            nativeAdListener.onNativeAdLoaded();
        }
    });

    NativeAdOptions adOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder().build();

    builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions);

    AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

            if (nativeAdListener != null) {
                nativeAdListener.onNativeAdError();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            super.onAdClicked();
        }
    }).build();

    adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


    return nativeAd[0];


}

private void populateNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd, UnifiedNativeAdView adView) {

    MediaView mediaView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media_main);
    adView.setMediaView(mediaView);
    adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
    adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action));
    adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_app_icon));

    ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());


    if (nativeAd.getCallToAction() == null) {
        adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getIcon() == null) {
        adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(
                nativeAd.getIcon().getDrawable());
        adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
    VideoController vc = nativeAd.getVideoController();
    if (vc.hasVideoContent()) {

        vc.setVideoLifecycleCallbacks(new VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoEnd() {
                super.onVideoEnd();
            }
        });
    }


}
public interface NativeAdListener {
    void onNativeAdLoaded();

    void onNativeAdError();
}
 }
```

Inside your `Acitivity` class layout file , ad two `Framelayouts`

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/ad_container_one"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:id="@+id/ad_container_two"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ad_container_one"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.47000003" />
```

Now Inside your activity or fragment make Two objects of Adutils class

```
   AdUtils adUtilOne;
   AdUtils adUtilTwo;
```

now you have to initialize both objects by passing context to the constructor and , framelayout, adlayout and adId to the load method.Create the `initAds` method in activity which calls the initialization.

```
    public void initAds(){
    String adIdOne="Your_ad_id";
    String adIdTwo="Your_ad_id";

    adUtilOne=  new AdUtils(this).loadNativeAd(frameLayoutAdOne,R.layout.ad_one, adIdOne);
    adUtilTwo= new AdUtils(this).loadNativeAd(frameLayoutAdOne,R.layout.ad_two, adIdTwo);

    adUtilOne.setNativeAdListener(new AdUtils.NativeAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNativeAdLoaded() {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onNativeAdError() {
            frameLayoutAdOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    
    adUtilTwo.setNativeAdListener(new AdUtils.NativeAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNativeAdLoaded() {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onNativeAdError() {
            frameLayoutAdOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}
```

and call the method after findviewsby id is done.

Comment: what is frameLayoutAdOne in   'adUtilTwo= new AdUtils(this).loadNativeAd(frameLayoutAdOne,R.layout.ad_two, adIdTwo);'  it is showing me error

Comment: framelayout is the view inside your activity layout file where you want to show native ad

Answer (score 1):

This question is bit old but sharing my solution because some one in future looking for solution will benefit from the answer

**Note**: This solution is not for Recyclerview or Listview.
To show two native ads in same activity you need two FrameLayouts in your activity xml and two nativead xmls(if you want to show ads in different sizes otherwise one is enough).
Admob now provide method [loadAds()](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start#loadads) with the help of which you can request upto 5 ads at once. eg:

```
adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), 5);
```

To load two Native ads here is code sample

```
int loadingCount = 0;

public void loadNativeAd(){

    AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(activity.getApplicationContext(),"YOUR_NATIVEAD_ID");

    builder.forNativeAd(
            new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                    
                    // To count adload because loadAds() is equal to calling 
                    // loadAd() the number of ads you pass to loadAds() method.
                    loadingCount+=1; 

                    Log.d("NativeAdOnLoad", "Native Ad loaded "+loadingCount);


                    // If this callback occurs after the activity is destroyed
                    // You must call destroy on old ads when you are done with them,
                    // otherwise you will have a memory leak.
                    if (nativeAd != null) {
                        nativeAd.destroy();
                    }
                    nativeAd = unifiedNativeAd;
                    if (loadingCount == 1){

                        FrameLayout frameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder);

                        NativeAdView adView =
                                (NativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                                        .inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null);
                        populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
                        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
                        frameLayout.addView(adView);
                    }else if (loadingCount>1){
                        FrameLayout frameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder1);
                        loadingCount=0;
                       
                        // if you want to show ads in different sizes 
                        // pass your second layout here
                        NativeAdView adView =
                                (NativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                                        .inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null);
                        populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
                        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
                        frameLayout.addView(adView);
                    }

                }
            });

    VideoOptions videoOptions =
            new VideoOptions.Builder().setStartMuted(true).build();

    NativeAdOptions adOptions =
            new NativeAdOptions.Builder().setVideoOptions(videoOptions).build();

    builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions);

    AdLoader adLoader =
            builder
                    .withAdListener(
                            new AdListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                                    String error =
                                            String.format(
                                                    "domain: %s, code: %d, message: %s",
                                                    loadAdError.getDomain(),
                                                    loadAdError.getCode(),
                                                    loadAdError.getMessage());
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                    activity,
                                                    "Failed to load native ad with error " + error,
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            })
                    .build();

    adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(),2);

}
```

And here is populateUnifiedNativeAdView function.

```
private void populateUnifiedNativeAdView(NativeAd nativeAd, NativeAdView adView) {
    // Set the media view.
    adView.setMediaView((MediaView) adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media));

    // Set other ad assets.
    adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
    adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body));
    adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action));
    adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_app_icon));
    adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price));
    adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_stars));
    adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store));
    adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser));

    // The headline and mediaContent are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
    ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
    adView.getMediaView().setMediaContent(nativeAd.getMediaContent());

    // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
    // check before trying to display them.
    if (nativeAd.getBody() == null) {
        adView.getBodyView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getBodyView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getCallToAction() == null) {
        adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getIcon() == null) {
        adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(
                nativeAd.getIcon().getDrawable());
        adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getPrice() == null) {
        adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAd.getPrice());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) {
        adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
        adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                .setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
        adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
        adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
        adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // This method tells the Google Mobile Ads SDK that you have finished populating your
    // native ad view with this native ad.
    adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

    // Get the video controller for the ad. One will always be provided, even if the ad doesn't
    // have a video asset.
    VideoController vc = nativeAd.getMediaContent().getVideoController();

    // Updates the UI to say whether or not this ad has a video asset.
    if (vc.hasVideoContent()) {

        // Create a new VideoLifecycleCallbacks object and pass it to the VideoController. The
        // VideoController will call methods on this object when events occur in the video
        // lifecycle.
        vc.setVideoLifecycleCallbacks(new VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoEnd() {
                // Publishers should allow native ads to complete video playback before
                // refreshing or replacing them with another ad in the same UI location.
                super.onVideoEnd();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And just call the below function where you want to load the NativeAd

```
    loadNativeAd();
```